Is there an Android File Manager app that allows to browse rapidly through photos stored on a remote SMB share?
I have a desktop with Open Media Vault 6 installed, and I have set up a SMB 2 (also tested with 3) share on it so that my girlfriend and I can get access to our photos from any device via Tailscale VPN. When I connect to the share via my laptop connected to the VPN (I made sure to connect with the public IP addres of my OMV desktop and not through the local network), I can see my 4k photos loading quite fast in Windows Explorer, like 20 per second or so. However, if I connect to the share through an Android file explorer like Solid Explorer, File Manager Plus or MiXplorer the images a quite slow to load, like 1 or 2 per second. The only one that I found that was faster than the rest (loads around 5-10 pictures per second) is X-Plore, but it has no galery layout so browsing through photos is really not great.
To add more context, I have a Pixel 8 with Android 14 and my girlfriend has a Galaxy S22.
I don't know why nearly all File Manager apps are slow and I was wondering if some of you would have any guess and suggestions of things to try to improve the speed.
Thanks

Hi, please note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. While the question body has reasonable scope, the current title is considered problematic. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, Software Recommendations Stack Exchange instead.
